problem with scale when importing into body
I can't solve the problem. There is a web application. When I open it from my phone, it displays correctly.
But as soon as I add head import (<script src="https://something.js"></script>), the working area increases. When viewing from a computer, the difference is not noticeable. But when viewing from a phone, the display changes.
When you open it from your phone, part of the screen is shown.
I mean that previously, the content was displayed in full, but after importing the height and width of the body increases and it does not fit.
How can I make sure that the import does not affect width and height?

What's being imported? Is it just function definitions, or is there code that runs on import?

@Carcigenicate
adv integration. like link
